# Partial differential equations in $ \infty $

Tags: partial-derivative

Suppose that we have
$$\begin{cases} u_{tt}=u_{xx} \text{ for }\ 0 < x < \pi ,\ t > 0\\
u(x,0)=8\sin x \\ u_{t}(x,0)=0\\ u(0,t)= u(\pi,t)=0\end{cases}$$

find

$ \lim_{t \rightarrow  \infty }u( \frac{\pi}{4},t)  $=?

Comment: I think this would be a reasonable question if you gave the separation of variables solution and then asked for the limit of that expression. As it stands you have not supplied enough of your own thoughts.

Comment: @Ian : There could be a way to calculate this limit without knowing the exact solution (Even if I'm not sure it's possible here)

Answer (score 0):

$$u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$$

$$u_{tt}(x,t)=X(x)T''(t)$$

$$u_{xx}(x,t)=X''(x)T(t)$$

$$u_{tt}=u_{xx} \Rightarrow X(x)T''(t)=X''(x)T(t)$$

We are looking for a non-trivial solution, so we assume that $X(x),T(t) \neq 0$ and thus we can divide the above  relation by the product $X(x)T(t)$.

So we have:

$$\frac{T''(t)}{T(t)}=\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}=-\lambda$$

Now use the initial and boundary conditions and solve the two problems that you will get.